# Tableau: How to changes font color based on value

Tags: tableau-api

Two questions:
1. I have a report that I need to change the font color if the threshold value is not met. If CompositeV < .90 the font color should be RED else BLACK.

2. How to I add an indicator based on #1

[image]

I have the color coded indicator, but I need to change the font color if it is less than .90 to red.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a calculated field:

```
If CompositeV < .90
THEN "RED"
ELSE "BLACK"
END
```

And then add that field to the color shelf.  I think I'd need more information about what type of indicator you're looking for? You could use that calculated field to further indicate which values met your condition.

Comment: that was my guess too, and I was able to create a calculated field based on the logic I provided. Thanks.

Comment: I have the indicator already. What I want to accomplish is changing the font color to "Red" when it is less than < .90

Comment: It looks like from your screenshot that your percentage value is on the row shelf, and your indicator field is on the detail shelf. Tableau will not dynamically change the headers.  To have the number itself change color it needs to be in the text field, and the indicator on the color shelf.  You can add the percentage on the row shelf as well to preserve column like format. [link](http://imgur.com/a/JtDNE) You can hide the header.